# How to enable foreign/accentuated letters popup on ukelele (.keylayout) custom keyboard keypress?

Tags: keyboard, keybindings, internationalization, ukelele, character-map

I have created and installed a custom keyboard layout with the ukelele application.
This keyboard is installed here :
`~/Library/Keyboard Layouts/my-custom-layout.keylayout`

When the default english Mac OS keyboard is selected, I'm able to press a key and have a popup with accentuated variations of that letter.

[image]

This is not the case when my custom keyboard is selected.

I have seen that I could edit the `Keyboard-**.plist` files here :
`/System/Library/Input Methods/PressAndHold.app/Contents/PlugIns/PAH_Extension.appex/Contents/Resources`

But I don't know which one should be used in my case ?
In the System preferences, this keyboard appears on the "Others" section...
[image]

Comment: A good place to ask such questions is the Ukelele group, where the author of the app also often participates.   https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ukelele-users

Comment: You could try creating your layout in the .bundle format, where the language can be specified.  But I am not sure the character picker feature will work with layouts not provided by Apple.